# Problem with Openlayers and Cloud-optimized GeoTIFF

Tags: openlayers, geotiff

I'm using the latest Openlayers with a COG (cloud-optimized-geotiff). It works fine when I set the map view to the bounds of the GeoTIFF while creating the layer, but if I try setting the view to something else (or not changing it after creating the layer), the OpenLayers map freezes with almost 100% CPU usage. Has anyone else had this problem?

Code here https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-forked-6w9sf?file=/main.js. With the view as-is (centred on the GeoTIFF), it freezes; with the view set to the View from the just-added GeoTIFF layer, it works fine. I need to display the GeoTIFF layer in the context of the larger base map, so I need to use a different view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

WebGL tile layers cannot be reprojected, so you will need to reproject the base layer https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-forked-tmswq?file=/main.js You can predefine the possible projections using proj4, or you could load them as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html when the GeoTIFF view promise resolves.

(answer courtesy of mike-000)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).